# jQuery - on load of dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, data-binding, slick.js

I'm trying to fire an event after certain elements are binded into the view.

I'm trying to use the following but it doesn't work:

```
$(".featWrap").on("load", ".box", function() {
     $(".featWrap").slick({dots: true});
});
```

Using the following works, but I need to fire the event when the element is binded, not when its clicked:

```
$(".featWrap").on("click", ".box", function() {
     $(".featWrap").slick({dots: true});
});
```

I was thinking about using a custom event after its binded, but I can't do so because the function that binds the data looks like this:

```
APP.bind["game.featuredPrizes"]    = APP.get("user.featuredPrizes", function (featuredPrizes) {
    return featuredPrizes.map(formatFeatured);
});
```

Comment: bytheway `.load()` is deprecated in jquery ver  1.8  and removed from 3.0

Comment: @FerVargas add html plz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to listen for new dinamically added elements you may use [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events). Here you find a [documents browser support for mutation events](http://help.dottoro.com/ljfvvdnm.php#additionalEvents).

A little demo:

```js
// listen for the newly added elements with class box
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '.box', function (e) {
  var element = e.target;
  setTimeout(function () {
    $(element).fadeOut(1000, function () {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  }, 2000);
});

$(function () {
  
  // create and add a new element on the fly
  
  $('#insert').on('click', function (e) {
    $('<div/>', {
      class: 'test',
      text: 'Test Generic'
    }).appendTo('body');
  });
  
  $('#insertBox').on('click', function (e) {
    $('<div/>', {
      class: 'box',
      text: 'Test Generic'
    }).appendTo('body');
  });

});
```

```css
.box {
  padding: 1em;
  background: #ffa;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.test {
  padding: 1em;
  background: #008000;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<button id="insertBox">Insert box</button>
<button id="insert">Insert a generic element</button>
```

Comment: This did the trick, it now detects when the element is added. The problem now is that slick is not initializing.. But that is unrelated to this.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to fire the event when the element is binded, not when its clicked:

This doesn't seem possible

```
$("#id").on("bind", function() {
    // This is what you want to achieve
    // Calling this function when an event has been binded to $("#id")
    console.log("bind click binded");
});

$("#id").bind("click", function() {
    console.log("click binded");
});
```